# ServiceProvider.GetServices does not return services when services have been added

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, service-provider

I am trying to use a service provider within a test method

First I setup a ServiceCollection

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddTransient<IMyPlugin, MyPlugin>();
```

`IMyPlugin` inherits from the interface `IPlugin`

I then build a service provider

```
serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Then I try to get my service from it

```
var myServices = serviceProvider.GetServices<IPlugin>()
            .Where(x=>x.GetType().IsAbstract == false).ToList();
```

This list is always empty, even if I remove the `Where` clause

I have now found that if I replace `IMyPlugin` with `IPlugin` this does now give me a list. But why do I have to do this, because `IMyPlugin` inherits from `IPlugin`?

Comment: What happens if you do `.GetServices<IMyPlugin>`?

Comment: I get no services back

Comment: @Paul The service collection is unaware of any types registered as `IPlugin` based on what you have shown so far it will only be aware of `IMyPlugin`

Comment: Why is it unaware?  IMyPlugin inherits from IPlugin?

Comment: The service collection is only aware of the types you explicitly register. The default built-in DI is very simple as designed.